# Updating to the latest MPAndroidChart version

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I  need  to implement the latest new [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) feature for the X-Axis - Entry constructor (float x, float y) whereas I am currently stuck with Entry(float y, int xIndex) as I built my project using MPAndroidChart v2-2-4.

I have been working on this project for 2-3 months.
Is it at all feasible to import the  MPAndroidChart v3.0b lib and use the new methods or is it a matter of throwing it all away and rebuilding.

Obviously the x value constructors would need recoding but I am wondering if it is at all compatible for the majority of existing code. Has anyone any experience on this?

The code draws 3 line charts from a database and will have a Monthly series X-axis. Currently it does just that only with an indexed X axis.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to MPAndroidChart 2.1.6 to 3.0.0.   My chart has 3 lines on one line chart. I used all the existing code.  The only changes were in the modified Entry class as you noted and simple changes to deprecated methods [ex: setCircleSize() in now setCircleRadius() ]. I would recommend keeping your existing code.